# How to convert a Pandas series into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I've been running some groupings on a dataframe that I have and saving the results in variables. However, I just noticed that the variables are actually being saved as series rather than dataframes.

I've seen tutorials/docs on how to convert a series to a dataframe, but all of them show only static data (by manually typing each of the values into an array), and this isn't an option for me, because I have over 2 million rows in my data frame.

So if I have

```
TopCustomers = raw_data.groupby(raw_data['Company'])['Total Records'].sum()
Top10Customers = TopCustomers.sort_values().tail(10)
```

How can I turn Top10Customers into a dataframe? I need it because not all plots work with series.

The syntax `frame = { 'Col 1': series1, 'Col 2': series2 }` doesn't work because I only have 1 series

Comment: I think you can use the following command: `pd.DataFrame(TopCustomers.sort_values().tail(10))`

Comment: `Top10Customers.to_frame()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I think that method is not aligning the columns properly, maybe its just visual but Im noticing that by using that, the 'Total Records' is position way above the 'companies' column. I used `Top10CustomersDF = pandas.DataFrame({'Customers':Top10Customers.index, 'Total Records':Top10Customers.values})` and it got aligned

Comment: That's because `companies` is currently the index. If so, what you want is `Top10Customers.reset_index()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here a small example with data:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = pd.DataFrame({'Company':['A', 'A','B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'Total Records':[2,3,6,4,5,10]})
TopCustomers = raw_data.groupby(raw_data['Company'])['Total Records'].sum()
```

Indeed `type(TopCustomers)` is pandas.core.series.Series
The following turns it in a DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(TopCustomers)
```

Otherwise `.to_frame()` works equally well as indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.to_frame()` method and it will turn it into a `pd.DataFrame`.